# Specifying history for delay differential equations ``near infinity'' (using NDSolve)

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Consider the following DDE:

$ f''(x)+ f(x+ 1) = 0.$

For $ x \gg 1$, this DDE should approximately reduce to that of a simple harmonic oscillator: $f''(x)+f(x) \approx 0$. Suppose that for some physical reason I require $f(x) = \sin{x}$ for large $x$ and then use this as a ``history'' for the above DDE. I am then interested to see what $f(x)$ is in the vicinity of $x=0$.

The problem is that (not surprisingly) depending on where I set the history condition (when using NDSolve), I get a different answer for $f(x)$ near $x=0$. Any suggestions for how to properly handle this?

Comment: Plase read [Math Stackexchange question 2765086](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2765086) "Writing the recursive as explicit" and its answers for ideas. Also see [MSE question 2245492] (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2245492) "Continuous recursive iteration" for $\,f'(x)=f(x-1).$

Comment: Thanks Somos, but my question is how to use NDSolve to handle this problem.

Comment: Ah, yes. I should have mentioned that I don't think `NDSolve[]` is going to help.

Comment: In the documentation of NDSolveValue I found an example which might help(`NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == x[t] (x[t - Pi] - x'[t - 1]), 
  x[t /; t <= 0] == Cos[t]}, x, {t, 0, 8}]`): Instead of initial conditions try `f[t /; t >=  0] == Sin[t]`

Comment: That is what I meant by ``history''; in fact that is the only way NDSolve can integrate a DDE. Still if you set up the history at t>=0 and integrate from zero, you will get a different answer from a history at t>=1 which is integrated from t=1. And that is my problem, because how close to infinity is close enough? how do I know I can trust the result.

Comment: I am curious. How did you get from your DDE to $\,f''(x)+f(x) \approx 0\,$ since you want $\,f(x) \approx \sin x\,$ for large $x$? If you meant $\,f(x+2\pi)\,$ instead of $\,f(x+1)\,$ that would make sense.

Comment: You haven't accepted any answers to any of your questions. You can accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming an asymptotic 2Pi-periodic solution `f[t]==s Sin[t]+ c Cos[t]` 
the ode can be integrated:

first integration:

```
gl1 = f'[x] - f'[0] == Integrate[f[1 + u], {u, 0, x}] /. f -> (c Cos[#]+ s Sin[#] &)
gl1/. x->2Pi (* 2Piperiodic boundary conditions*)
(* True*)
```

second integration

```
gl2 = f[x] - f[0] - f'[0] x ==Integrate[f[1 + u], {v, 0, x}, {u, 0, v}] /.f -> (c Cos[#] + s Sin[#] &)
sol=Solve[gl2 /. x -> 2 Pi, s][[1]]
(*{s -> (c Sin[1])/(1 + Cos[1])}*)
```

Asymptotic solution:

```
fasy=(c Cos[#] + s Sin[#] )& /. sol /.c->1;
fasy[x]
(*Cos[x] + (Sin[1] Sin[x])/(1 + Cos[1])*)
```

The initial values evalute to

```
{fasy[0], Derivative[1][fasy][0]}
(*{1, Sin[1]/(1 + Cos[1])}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sol = NDSolve[{f''[x] + f[x + 1] == 0, f[x /; x >= 0] == Sin[x]}, f, {x, 0, 8Pi}][[1]]
Plot[{Evaluate[f[x] /. sol], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 8 Pi}]
```

Comment: For the case `x /; x >= 0` NDSolve returns `Sin[x] ` as result. Varying the lower limit for x (`x /; x >= x0` ) shows, that the initial values change and increase depending on x0.